# SuperSlim for Android: Get first header view

Tags: android, superslim

I noticed that SuperSlim does not return the first header when calling getChildAt(0), but the first (non-header) item in the first section.

How can I get the first header? I need it's height of other calculations.

Checking out the source code I found the function "getHeaderOrFirstViewForSection" which seems to be what I am lookin for, however it is declared private so I cannot access it.

Comment: Where do you call this getChildAt(0) from? can you post some code?

Comment: We tried to call getChildAt(0) on both the recyclerView and layoutmanager. However this is not an issue anymore as we were able to get the header with the following call : getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(0)

Comment: SuperSLiM keeps header views attached after section views to ensure they are drawn after the section content. As you've discovered, with recyclerView you shouldn't make assumptions about the ordering of children and just use findViewByPosition instead.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by this article https://github.com/2013mzhou/blog/blob/master/bug%26extend/Get%20StickyHeaderView%20in%20SuperSLiM.md .It's run well.

when useing like this

```
   final LayoutManager layout = new LayoutManager(getActivity());
    layout.setOnHeaderListener(new LayoutManager.StickyHeaderWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onStickyStateChanged(View header, int position) {
            Log.i("StickyHeaderWatcher",position+"");
            if (header instanceof TextView) {
                Log.i("StickyHeaderWatcher", ((TextView) header).getText().toString());
            }
        }
    });
```